# in elisp's let, how do you reference a variable bound in the same let while binding another variable?

Tags: emacs, elisp

```
(let ((a 1) (b (+ a 1)))
  (message a))
```

This throws the error

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable a)
```

What's the canonical way to do this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The canonical way is to use [`let*`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Local-Variables.html#index-let_002a-592) (also note that I added a `%s` format string to your `message` form):

```
(let* ((a 1) (b (+ a 1)))
  (message "%s" a))
```

The `let*` function allows you to reference other variables that have previously been defined.

Comment: Shorthand for `(let ... (let ... (let ...)))`.  You beat me by 10 seconds. :-)

Comment: There's the quick and the dead. ;-)